# Pull-up resistor value I2C; higher than 400 pf capacitance

Tags: resistors, i2c, pullup

I'm using 100 kHz I2C for communication with 12 slaves. I found that MAX capacitance is about 400 PF. when I calculate the pull up resistor value, it looks like i can go mucher higher in capacitance. Is this correct?

Using 5V, and VOL = 0.4V for IOL = 3mA

**Rmin=5V−0.4V /3mA = 1533 ohm**
This means I can go as low as 1533 ohm.

If C bus is 650pf

**Rmax=1000ns/(Cbus*0.8473) = 1000ns/(650PF *0.8473) = 1800 ohm.**

So If I choose a pull up resistor about 1.8K, It will satisfy BOTH Rmin and Rmax equitation. My Bus can handle up to 650 PF capacitance.

Is this correct or do I miss something? Why goes official specs for 100kHz maximum till 400 pf?

Thanks!!
All Equitations comes from official I2C specs
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf  P55

(PS: The  I2C devices I use can also handle up to 20mA IOL for VOL = 0.4V. This means that Rmin can be way lower; Rmin=5V−0.4V /20mA = 230 ohm. My bus can handle much more capacitance)

Comment: Just piling up references: [Design calculations for robust I2C communications](https://www.edn.com/design/analog/4371297/Design-calculations-for-robust-I2C-communications)

Comment: I have already read this. It does not answer my question :(

Comment: In Engineering there is a thing called "safe margins". If your calculations show that 1.8k pullup meets timing (Trise) margin even with 650pF load, it doesn't mean that all your other devices will reliably meet all other parameters at all process and temperature corners.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the pull up resistor for your bus is chosen depending on the bus capacitance. So higher the bus capacitance, you'll have to use a lower pull-up resistor. The criterion to be satisfied is that at the switching frequency, your pad should be able to charge to 90% of the rail voltage (which is a spec in i2c). The resistor pull-ups generally mentioned, correspond to different modes of operation of i2c.(like fast mode, fast mode plus, high speed mode). FM+ mode uses 1MHz signal and hence the resistor pull-up is calculated such that the bus is charged to rail voltage within 0.5us.

Now in your case, if you have a dc Iol requirement of 3mA @ Vol=0.4V then, it just means that you're supposed to be able to sink 3mA of current through the open drain transistor which you have. You may not need to worry about the drop across the pull-up resistor.

Also, I didn't get your Rmax calculation part, is it an equation mentioned in the i2c data sheet?

Comment: Please don't ask the OP any questions in your answer. That's what the comments section is for :) but good answer nonetheless +1

Comment: Yes @KingDuken, I wish not to ask question in my answer, but Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to comment till my reputations is 50+ which is unruly. :)

Comment: Yes, all calculation comes from the official specs!

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf

Comment: The problem is official I2C spec for 100 kHz goes maximum till 400pf . However From my calculations, i can go up to 650 pf.

Comment: Thanks Berkay, looks like they have considered Tr rise time spec for some 10-90% or so in which case your formula make sense. If your bus capacitance can go up to 650pF, then you'll have to use a lower Rpullup. But the catch would be to meet Tfal min and Max specs, at the mentioned switching frequency.

Comment: They consider it from 30% to 70%. But this does not change anything. The official spec is limits maximum capacitance to 400 pf. That's something I cannot understand. What's the Tfal btw?

Comment: Tfal is the fall time at the bus, where the Tfal is supposed to be lower than 120ns and higher than some value which will be mentioned in datasheet (it'll proportional to the external pull-up voltage). Again, regarding the 650pF, I don't think it should be an issue as long as you're able to meet the other spec required for i2c (which includes tfall, bus voltage to be higher than 90% of rail voltage, lower than 10% rail voltage). Indirectly you'll have more power which is up to you.

Comment: Tfal for 100 Khz is 300ns. But how is this related to the pull-up resistor? Rmin formula is formula to ensure the device can pull the line LOW. Rmax formula is the formula to bring the line back to high, considering T rise. I have not seen T fal anywhere.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my bad. Tfal is not a spec externally. But when the max capacitance of 400pF is mentioned, it's known that the datasheet's mentioned Tfal values will be violated with a higher bus capacitance. This is because the i2c would be designed considering the 400pF cap discharging through the open drain transistor.(the size is the transistor/drive will be based on this). The higher cap load will affect your charging and static currents, in turn your power consumption too. So in short, if Tfal or power is not a major concern to you, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Oh okey.. So It will be impossible for me to go further than 400 pf? (using repeater/buffer is not an option for my application)

Comment: I don't know if a buffer would suffice, nonetheless you'll solve capacitance issue. Given that the signal will be a slow varying signal (100kHz) at the i2c output, you may have T_on pulse width varied at the output of the buffer. If you're okay to live with a distorted duty cycle signal, should be fine I suppose.